# Failed to open dir on server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In localhost I can delete, copy my folder and files just fine. However, after I host my web app, those functions don't work on the server.

Here is the error that I got:

> Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException'
>   with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator
>   ::__construct(/home/solution/public_html/portalprojectcdr/backend/web/The Library/ISU/New directory) : failed to open dir: No such file or
>   directory' in /home/solution/public_html/portal/backend/views/site
>   /submit_upload_to_server.php:73

Comment: **No such file or directory**

Comment: but i double check, they are exist and the path is just like in localhost.
is it because of Recursive function?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a permissions problem? The account the web server runs as may not have read/execute access to the directory or it's parent(s).

Comment: Maybe, but i don't know how to set permission. Is there any guide?

Answer (score 0):

As there seems to be a new directory involved in your error, i suppose you should check permission and owners for your files.

Please mass downvote if this advice in unsecure, but i use it on production :
Define the user www-data as owner of the file and folder that must be writable.
If you are not on production, you can try a naughty chmod 777 where needed, to see if your problem is really permission related.

Don't forget to put permission back to normal after your test.

Comment: i am new to such permission thing.
can you guide me?

Comment: I am an adept of the bad practices, aka giving quick and unsecure advices, but especially for this case, you should really read about file permission. You will use them for years, and often face trouble with. More : your server security depends on your comprehension of this point.